# how to parse a 3D dxf to kml

Tags: kml, dxf

How can I parse a 3D dxf to a kml file?

I'm looking for an answer that could point me to suitable references.

The DXF is pasted below:

```
  0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1006
  9
$UCSORG
  10
0.0
  20
0.0
  30
0.0
  9
$UCSXDIR
  10
1.0
  20
0.0
  30
0.0
  9
$TILEMODE
  70
1
  9
$UCSYDIR
  10
0.0
  20
1.0
  30
0.0
  9
$EXTMIN
  10
0.0
  20
0.0
  30
0.0
  9
$EXTMAX
  10
100000.0
  20
100000.0
  30
10000.0
    0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.005250
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.003133
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.003133
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.813357
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.801557
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.813357
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.801557
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.813357
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.813357
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.801557
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.801557
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.032616
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.032616
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.034733
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.802348
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.801557
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.801557
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.034733
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.003133
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.034733
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.003133
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.034733
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.034733
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.003133
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.003133
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.114152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.813357
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.813357
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.813357
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.813357
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.813357
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.003133
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.003133
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.003133
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.005250
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.003133
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.003133
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.003133
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.005250
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.003133
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.003133
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.005250
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.005250
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.802348
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.005250
 20
57.804507
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.005250
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.011033
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.011033
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.801557
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.801557
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.801557
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.011033
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.011033
 21
57.802348
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.801557
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.801557
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.801557
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.802348
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.801557
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.018933
 21
57.801557
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.802348
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.802348
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.004152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.004152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.802348
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.802348
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.034733
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.034733
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.034733
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.034733
 20
57.807457
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.804507
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.804507
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.804507
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.032616
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.034733
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.032616
 20
57.810407
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.034733
 21
57.807457
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.034733
 22
57.807457
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.034733
 23
57.807457
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.026833
 20
57.812567
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.032616
 21
57.810407
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.032616
 22
57.810407
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.032616
 23
57.810407
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.813357
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.114152
 12
-105.018933
 22
57.813357
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.018933
 23
57.813357
 33
-0.114152
  0
3DFACE
  8
Body
 62
0
 420
255
 10
-105.018933
 20
57.813357
 30
-0.004152
 11
-105.026833
 21
57.812567
 31
-0.004152
 12
-105.026833
 22
57.812567
 32
-0.114152
 13
-105.026833
 23
57.812567
 33
-0.114152
  0
ENDSEC
  0
EOF
```

Comment: convert it online with http://demos.fmeserver.com/easytranslator/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend FME to do the job.   (http://www.safe.com/)   The ability to manipulate datasets to/from many different formats and easily wrap them into batch files will more than pay for itself over time.

Comment: this can done online with http://demos.fmeserver.com/easytranslator/index.html

Comment: Thx. tried this...getting "fatal errors" when I feed it the DXF.

Comment: @val can you post the 3d dxf file online?

Comment: @Mapperz: File pasted above.

Comment: @Mapperz: seems it has worked. I had previously failed to select a coordinate system (I let it guess). This time i selected WGS84. Just playing with the KML at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the GDAL [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) tool to convert a file from DXF to a KML.

ogr2ogr -f "KML" out.kml in.dxf -s_srs "source srs" -t_srs EPSG:4326

This will require that the DXF be georeferenced, and that you know can determine the spatial reference system of the source.

Comment: Thx. I've georeferenced it to lat/long as I'm thinking this could be the easiest to use (at least to start). Normally I deal with UTMs.

Comment: I tried DXF file you added to the question with GDAL version 1.11.1, and assumed the spatial reference was WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) and was able to produce a KML that loaded in Google Earth.

Comment: You can also convert directly from the UTM based files by specifying the correct [UTM zone EPSG identifier](http://reference.mapinfo.com/common/docs/mapxtend-dev-web-none-eng/miaware/doc/guide/xmlapi/coordsys/systems.htm), it looks like this data would be in UTM 13 North - so it would be EPSG:32613 for the source srs.

Comment: Does this conversion restrict the data to 2D? I have a 3D DXF. In GE it seems to only plot the 2D projection, or a slice of my model. Also, when I retrieve information on Code 4326 here http://www.epsg-registry.org/, it seems to convert to a 2D projection, i.e. (Type = GeodeticCRS (geographic 2D)". I want a 3D DXF converted to a KML (also in 3D).